# drupal 8 date are very long

Tags: date, drupal, long-integer, drupal-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/422wJ.png)

Hello in drupal 8.0.0 when I created a new content the date is too long:

11/23/2015 - 20:54 America/Bogota11 2015-11-23T20:54:19-05:0020151130America/Bogotax302015: f2015Mon, 23 Nov 2015 20:54:19 -050011pm302015 23America/Bogota fAmerica/Bogota2015-11-23T20:54:19-05:0008pm -05:0020-05:00

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the translation to spanish:

If you have in spanish this is the answer:

Inicio->Administración->Configuración->Regional e idioma->Formato de fecha y hora
And find the text "m/d/Y - H:i"
Click in "Filtro"

Appear two translations, the first is brong,
change "D, m/d/Y - H:i
en contexto: formato de fecha PHP"
And put "D, m/d/Y - H:i"

And save,

If the problem persists
Go to:
Inicio->Administración->Configuración->Regional e idioma->Formato de fecha y hora
And
change "D, m/d/Y - H:i
en contexto: formato de fecha PHP"
And put "D, m/d/Y - H:i"